# Help me find the mistake in my solution of the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fibonacci-numbers

Let $x_1=1, x_2=2,$
$$x_n=x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}, (n>2)$$
The task is to find:
$$\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}!$$
My attempt at solution:
We write the recursive formula as:
$$x_n-x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}=0$$
The characteristic equation is then defined as:
$$\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0$$
with solutions:
$\lambda_{1/2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$
Since the solutions are real and different, we can write our sequence as:
$$x_n=c_1\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^n+c_2\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^n$$
for $n=1$: $x_1=1=c_1\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}+c_2\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$
for $n=2$: $x_2=2=c_2\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^2+c_2\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^2$
When I solved the system I got: $c_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, c_2=-1$
So, our sequence is now:
$$x_n=\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^{n+1}-\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^n$$
Then we have:
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}!=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\cdot\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}\cdot\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n-2}}\cdot\cdot\cdot\frac{x_2}{x_1}\cdot\frac{x_1}{x_0}=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_0}$$
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_0}=\frac{\big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\big)^{n+2}-\big(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\big)^{n+1}}{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-1}=$$
$$-\frac{\big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\big)^{n+2}-\big(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\big)^{n+1}}{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}\bigg/\frac{:\big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\big)^{n+2}}{:\big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\big)^{n+2}}=$$
$$-\frac{1-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\cdot\big(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\big)^{n+2}}$$
So the limit is now:
$$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}!=-\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\cdot\big(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\big)^{n+2}}=\frac{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}-1}{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\bigg)^{n+2}=\infty$$
Is that correct?

Comment: Do you really mean to find the limit of the _factorial_ of $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$? If so, what do you mean by the factorial of a non-integer? $\Gamma(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}+1)$, perhaps? If so, since the gamma function is continuous at the relevant point, why not just take the limit of the $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$s -- which is well known to be $\phi$ -- and then compute $\Gamma(\phi+1)$ once and for all?

Comment: Without all the thing you've done solving $x_n$ explicitly, you could just say $x_{n+1}/x_0 \to \infty$ since $x_n\to \infty$.. so I suggest you've read the question wrong or you are misunderstanding what is meant by "Factorial" of $x_{n+1}/x_n$

Comment: I assume that "!" is not part of the expression we want to find, but instead the interpunctation of the surrounding English sentence, which is an imperative.

Comment: My God, that was an exclamation mark in the exercise. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The error was in calculate the $c_i$. It must be $c_2=1$